# Auto-provisioning not creating new node pool

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to set up [auto-provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning) on Google's Kubernetes service GKE. I created a cluster with both auto-scaling and auto-provisioning like so:

```
gcloud beta container clusters create "some-name" --zone "us-central1-a" \
  --no-enable-basic-auth --cluster-version "1.13.11-gke.14" \
  --machine-type "n1-standard-1" --image-type "COS" \
  --disk-type "pd-standard" --disk-size "100" \
  --metadata disable-legacy-endpoints=true \
  --scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append" \
  --num-nodes "1" --enable-stackdriver-kubernetes --enable-ip-alias \
  --network "projects/default-project/global/networks/default" \
  --subnetwork "projects/default-project/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/default" \
  --default-max-pods-per-node "110" \
  --enable-autoscaling --min-nodes "0" --max-nodes "8" \
  --addons HorizontalPodAutoscaling,KubernetesDashboard \
  --enable-autoupgrade --enable-autorepair \
  --enable-autoprovisioning --min-cpu 1 --max-cpu 8 --min-memory 1 --max-memory 16
```

The cluster has 1 node pool with 1 node having 1 vCPU. I tried running a deployment which requests 4 vCPU, so it would clearly not be satisfied by the current node pool.

```
kubectl run say-lol --image ubuntu:18.04 --requests cpu=4 -- bash -c 'echo lolol'
```

Here is what I want to happen: The auto-scaler *should* fail to accommodate the new deployment, as the existing node pool doesn't have enough CPU. The auto-provisioner should try to create a **new node pool** with a new node of 4 vCPU to run the new deployment.

Here is what is happening: The auto-scaler fails **as expected**. But the auto-provisioner is doing nothing. The pod remains `Pending` indefinitely. No new node pools get created.

```
$ kubectl get events
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON              KIND         MESSAGE
50s         Warning   FailedScheduling    Pod          0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu.
4m7s        Normal    NotTriggerScaleUp   Pod          pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 1 Insufficient cpu
9m17s       Normal    SuccessfulCreate    ReplicaSet   Created pod: say-lol-5598b4f6dc-vz58k
9m17s       Normal    ScalingReplicaSet   Deployment   Scaled up replica set say-lol-5598b4f6dc to 1

$ kubectl get pod
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
say-lol-5598b4f6dc-vz58k   0/1     Pending   0          9m14s

$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                                       STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
gke-some-name-default-pool-4ec86782-bv5t   Ready    <none>   31m   v1.13.11-gke.14
```

Why isn't a new node pool getting created to run the new deployment?

EDIT: It seems the `cpu=4` is the problematic part. If I change to `cpu=1.5`, it works. A new node pool is created and the pods start running. However, I indicated `--max-cpu 8` so it should clearly be able to handle 4 vCPUs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue could be related to [allocatable CPU](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#memory_cpu). Please check the machine type that was created.

Specifying this `--max-cpu 8` does not mean that new node will have 8 cores. Instead it specifies the [maximum number of cores in the cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning?hl=en_US&_ga=2.252487561.-1642715745.1571764481#enable).

Changing to `--max-cpu 40` should give better results as it will allow for a bigger machine type to be created.

Comment: It looks like the problem is not the `bash -c 'echo lolol'` command, it is the `cpu=4`. If I run `kubectl run --image=nginx nginx-app --port=80 --requests cpu=1.5`, it works. It also works if I run `kubectl run say-lol --image ubuntu:18.04 --requests cpu=1.5 -- bash -c 'echo lolol'`. In both cases the new node pool is created and the pods will run. However, if i change the CPU to `cpu=4` (even for nginx-app), the node pool is not created and the pods never run. The pods remain `Pending` forever.

Comment: @AndyCarlson, nice catch. When my node got created, it created this machine type: n1-highcpu-2 which as [allocatable CPU of 1.93](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#memory_cpu), that is why 1.5 was able to fit.

Comment: Go to Menu>Kubernetes engine>Cluster>and please check the machine type that was created.

Comment: I believe this may be because of the default machine types, a default machine type with 4 CPU will have approx 16 GB RAM, so that machine can't be made. Do you have the same problem with CPU 3?

Comment: @danyL Yes the node type was `n1-highcpu-2`. It seems I need a `n1-highcpu-8` in order to get at least 4 allocatable CPU units. The issue was that `n1-highcpu-8` was forbidden by the `--max-cpu 8` because, as you pointed out, specifies the *cluster-wide maximum*. Changing to `--max-cpu 40` fixed the problem! You should add this to your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @AndyCarlson. Added to my post and I am glad hear it is working now.